# Iterate over identical rows in data tables

Tags: r

I have a data table with 3 columns like this:

```
dt <- data.table(
col1 = c("id1","id1","id1","id6","id3","id3"), 
col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
col3 = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"))
```

The  values in the col 1 are characters as well and 
I need to iterate over each row in this column. If they are identical, keep the last one from them  and retrieve from the  last two columns the corresponding values at that position. E.g, for `id1` I will keep only the third value and retrieve `C` from `col2` and `CC` from `col3`.
If there are unique rows, just retrieve the `col2` and `col3` as they are.

The output I need should be:

```
col1    col2   col3

id1     C      CC

id6     D      DD

id3     F      FF
```

I tried something like below and got "Error in if ,,, missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

```
for (i in nrow(dt)) {
 if (dt[i,1]!=dt[i+1,1]){
  dt[i, 2] = dt[i,2]
}
  else {
    dt[i,2] <- dt$QUESTION
 }
}
```

Any idea on how one can solve this out ? I don't have to stick with data table

Thank you

Comment: Couple coding bugs. In your `for` loop you have to write `1:nrow(dt)` so `i` iterates over a vector. Currently `i` is just 6. Also, there is no column `QUESTION` in your data table

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to approach this, but a simple way is to check for duplicates using the `duplicated` and keep the first value starting from the end:

```
dt[!duplicated(dt$col1, fromLast = T),]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `duplicated` answer is likely what you want. But just because I like my `dplyr` workflows:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarise_all(last)
```

The one catch is that it will sort by `col1`.